# how to wrap the numbers from the textview in android

Tags: java, android, replace, textview

In Android ,i have a TextView ,inside the textview ,it contains some text example(22 likes,some times 1 like or empty text).Here i want to get only numbers not characters.so using how to use the String.replaceAll() to get the numbers exactly without empty text.
Here is a sample code ...

```
textview.setText("2 Likes");
String com=textview.replaceAll("","");
```

Comment: Instead of this logic , you change your web services and fetch only number from their , because this is not a GOOD logic

Comment: is there any other method without modify the server?

Comment: Your problem solved or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `String.split` to split string in Array as :

```
textview.setText("2 Likes");
String strtxt=textview.getText();

String[] arrliks = strtxt.split(" ");  
String num_of_likes=arrliks[0]; //<<< get 2 here
```

and you can also use  regex expressions to split string

**EDIT :**

you call also use `String.replaceAll`  as :

```
   String com=textview.getText();
   String liks = "likes";
   String str_new   ="";
  if (com.toLowerCase().indexOf(liks) != -1) {
     str_new=com.replaceAll(" Likes","");
   }else{
     str_new=com.replaceAll(" like","");
   }
```

Comment: suppose if 22 likes how to split

Comment: @RajeshLawrance : if you have static pattern like 2 likes , 33333 likes , 23293232 likes ,... then just use my answer this will give u number of likes on o index after spiting string on the basis of space

Comment: @RajeshLawrance : what prob u are getting now?

Comment: sometime it comes 1 like.what to do?

Comment: @RajeshLawrance : see my edit answer . and u have lots of methods to play with string in java . just search for String operations in java

Answer (score 0):

If your text always come like this means(32 likes , 2 likes)

You can use substring function

```
If(yourstring.length>0)
{

    string result = yourstring.substring(0,yourstring.index(" "));
}
else
{
Do whatever here..
}
```

This will result in cutting the numeric part alone.But make `sure that always a space` should come after numeric..

Comment: yes text will come always like this with space after numeric value

Comment: suppose empty textview will come,what will do?

Comment: The method index(String) is undefined for the type String in line of .index.i got the error like this

Comment: The method index(String) is undefined for the type String in line of .index.i got the error like this –

Comment: TextView like = (TextView) rll.findViewById(R.id.like); like.setText("22 likes"); sometime like.setText("2 like"); –

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the number of likes by using regular expressions:

```
     String txt = textview.getText();
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+).*");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);

    if (m.find()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(am.group(1));
    }
```